# Inconsistency running a clojure jar from command line

Tags: jdbc, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have a clojure program that at some point executes a function called `db-rebuild-files-table`.
This function takes a directory filename as a single string argument and calls a recursive function that descends into the directory file tree, extracts certain data from the files there and logs each file in a mysql database. The end result of this command is a "files" table populated by all files in the tree under the given directory.

What I need is to be able to run this command periodically from the shell.

So, I added the `:gen-class` directive in the file containing my `-main` function that actually calls `(db-rebuild-files-table *dirname*)`. I run `lein uberjar` and generate a jar which I can then execute with:

`java -jar my-project-SNAPSHOT-1.0.0-standalone.jar namespace.containing.main`

Sure enough, the function runs, but in the database there only exists a single entry, for the directory *dirname*. When I execute the **exact** same sexp in the clojure REPL I get the right behaviour: **all the file tree** under *dirname* get processed.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the call `(db-rebuild-files-table *dirname*)` behave inconsistently when called from the REPL and when executed from the command line?

[EDIT] Whats even weirder is that I get no error anywhere. All function calls seem to work as they should. I can even run the -main function in the REPL and it updates the table correctly.

Comment: What version of Clojure are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this works in the REPL, but not when executed stand-alone, then I would guess that you may be bitten by the laziness of Clojure.

Does your code perhaps need a `doseq` in order to get the benefits of a side-effect (e.g. writing to your database)?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you! I wrote my answer above just before you posted this.
\[EDIT\]
 For the record, I will rewrite my implementation using doseq as you suggest since the file tree can be enormous, no need holding it all into memory with doall.

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it. It was a **very** insidious bug in my program. I got bitten by clojure's laziness.
My file-tree function used map internally, and so produced just the first value, the root directory. For some reason I still can't figure out, when executed at the REPL, evaluation was actually forced and the whole tree seq was produced. I just added a `doall` in my function and it solved it.

Still trying to figure why executing something at the REPL forces evaluation though. Any thoughts?

Comment: The REPL always prints the return value of the last expression given to it, so it needs to evaluate the sequence in order to print the last expression as output. In contrast, this is not true of a Clojure program running 'normally'. I get caught by this all the time (but it does make good sense)!